# Multi-column table produced by STATA: Why is the last column not spaced properly?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, stata

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\begin {landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{{\b Table 1.} {\i Effect of Health on Labour force activity in India }}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{cc}}
\hline\hline
                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)}     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)}     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(3)}     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(4)}     \\
                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Null Model }&\multicolumn{2}{c}{State FE}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Household FE}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Overall} \\
\hline
Health          &    0.164\sym{***}&  (0.005)&    0.168\sym{***}&  (0.005)&    0.199\sym{***}&  (0.009)&    0.054\sym{***}&  (0.004)\\
State           &                  &         &    0.000         &      (.)&    0.000         &      (.)&    0.014\sym{*}  &  (0.000)\\
Place of residence&                  &         &                  &         &    0.000         &      (.)&   -0.031\sym{***}&  (0.006)\\
Caste of head of the HH&                  &         &                  &         &    0.000         &      (.)&   -0.032\sym{***}&  (0.002)\\
Religion of head of the HH&                  &         &                  &         &    0.000         &      (.)&    0.011\sym{*}  &  (0.003)\\
MPCE quintile   &                  &         &                  &         &    0.000         &      (.)&   -0.017\sym{***}&  (0.002)\\
Children Below 5 years&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.017\sym{***}&  (0.003)\\
Children Between 6 and 14 years&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.036\sym{***}&  (0.002)\\
Log of Age      &                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.399\sym{***}&  (0.013)\\
Sex of Respondent&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.182\sym{***}&  (0.005)\\
Years of Schooling&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.041\sym{***}&  (0.000)\\
Marital Status  &                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.005         &  (0.006)\\
Spouse Employment&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &    0.05\sym{***}&  (0.005)\\
Physical Activity&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &    0.5\sym{***}&  (0.005)\\
Ever Consumed alcohol&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.004         &  (0.005)\\
Ever Smoked     &                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.008         &  (0.004)\\
\hline
Observations    &    5035         &         &    5035         &         &    2744         &         &    4921         &         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize Standardized beta coefficients; Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize Source: Authors Calculation from }\\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize The dependent variable is equal to 1 if a person is working or looking for work. Health as an indepdent variable is defined as 0 if an individual reported poor or fair health status,otherwise, it is 1.}\\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}




 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title. Besides, please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table. We need information about your document pages layout. Also, is it acceptable to have standard errors in separate rows?

Comment: @Zarko I have edit my code. I hope it is in good shape and in desired format. I thought of reporting  SE as a separate column. Some journals do it.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you're asking for? The "overall" text is centered between the 2 last columns.

Comment: Now situation is very different. Your table nicely fit in landscape page. However, you should use `threeparttable` See answer below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause of the ninth/last column taking up a lot more space than one would expect it to lies in the fact that one of the four `\multicolumn{9}{l}{...}` statements has a very long argument while the `l` column type does not allow automatic line breaking. This fact forces the overall width of the `tabular` environment to be (much) larger than the sum of the natural widths of the 9 columns. When this happens, LaTeX allocates the excess width to the final column. (As its column type happens to be `c`, lots of whitespace padding is inserted on both sides.) This choice may seem arbitrary; however, alternative allocation systems (such as widening all 9 columns proportionately) are every bit as arbitrary.

The solution is to allow automatic line breaking in the footnote cells. This may be done by replacing the `l` column type, which does not allow line breaking, with something like `p{1.4\textwidth}`, as the `p` column type is designed to allow automatic line breaking if and when needed.

In the following, I've applied a few more measures to increase the visual appeal of the table, such as aligning the numbers in columns 2, 4, 6, and 8 on their respective decimal markers. I hope you agree.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % allow alignment of numbers on decimal markers
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
% handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcii}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcix}[1]{\multicolumn{9}{@{}%
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.45\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{%{\b Table 1.} {\i 
  Effect of health on labour force activity in India\strut} %}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{3}{d{1.6}c} d{2.6}c @{}}
  \toprule
  &\mcii{(1)} &\mcii{(2)} &\mcii{(3)} &\mcii{(4)} \\
  &\mcii{Null Model} &\mcii{State FE} &\mcii{Household FE} &\mcii{Overall} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} 
  Health            & 0.164\sym{***}& (0.005)& 0.168\sym{***}& (0.005)& 0.199\sym{***}& (0.009)& 0.054\sym{***}& (0.004)\\
  State             & & & 0.000 & (.)& 0.000 & (.)& 0.014\sym{*} & (0.000)\\
  Place of residence& & & & & 0.000 & (.)& -0.031\sym{***}& (0.006)\\
  Caste of head of HH& & & & & 0.000 & (.)& -0.032\sym{***}& (0.002)\\
  Religion of head of HH& & & & & 0.000 & (.)& 0.011\sym{*}  & (0.003)\\
  MPCE quintile    & & & & & 0.000 & (.)& -0.017\sym{***}& (0.002)\\
  \addlinespace
  Children below 5 years& & & & & & & -0.017\sym{***}& (0.003)\\
  Children between 6 and 14 years& & & & & & & -0.036\sym{***}& (0.002)\\
  Log of age       & & & & & & & -0.399\sym{***}& (0.013)\\
  Sex of respondent& & & & & & & -0.182\sym{***}& (0.005)\\
  Years of schooling& & & & & & & -0.041\sym{***}& (0.000)\\
  \addlinespace
  Marital status   & & & & & & & -0.005 & (0.006)\\
  Spouse employment& & & & & & & 0.05\sym{***}& (0.005)\\
  Physical activity& & & & & & & 0.50\sym{***}& (0.005)\\
  Ever consumed alcohol& & & & & & & -0.004 & (0.005)\\
  Ever mmoked      & & & & & & & -0.008 & (0.004)\\
  \midrule
  Number of observations & \mc{5035} & & \mc{5035} & & \mc{2744} & & \mc{4921} &\\
  \bottomrule 
  \addlinespace
  \mcix{Standardized beta coefficients; Standard errors in parentheses}\\
  \mcix{Source: Authors salculations.}\\
  \mcix{The dependent variable is equal to 1 if a person is working or looking for work. 
        Health as an independent variable is 0 if an individual reported poor or fair 
        health status; otherwise, it is 1.}\\
  \mcix{\sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it was quite helpful

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that you after this:

[image]

For above table are used `\threeparttable` and `siunitx` packages as are usual at similar statistic tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

    
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty =,
    input-close-uncertainty=,
    table-align-text-after=false
        }
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Effect of Health on Labour force activity in India}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{S[table-format=-1.3{$^{***}$}]
                           S[table-format={(}1.3{)}] } @{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)}     
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)}     
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(3)}     
                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(4)}        \\
    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Null Model}
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{State FE}
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Household FE}
                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Overall}    \\
    \midrule
Health
    & 0.164\sym{***} & (0.005) & 0.168\sym{***} & (0.005) 
    & 0.199\sym{***} & (0.009) & 0.054\sym{***} & (0.004)   \\
State           
    &       &       & 0.000             & (.)   
    & 0.000 & (.)   & 0.014\sym{*}      & (0.000)           \\
Place of residence
    &       &       &                   &         
    & 0.000 & (.)   & -0.031\sym{***}   &  (0.006)          \\
Caste of head of the HH
    &       &       &                   &         
    & 0.000 & (.)   & -0.032\sym{***}   &  (0.002)          \\
Religion of head of the HH
    &       &       &                   &         
    & 0.000 & (.)   & 0.011\sym{*}      &  (0.003)          \\
MPCE quintile   
    &       &       &                   &         
    & 0.000 & (.)   & -0.017\sym{***}   &  (0.002)          \\
Children Below 5 years
    &       &       &                   &         
    &       &       & -0.017\sym{***}   &  (0.003)          \\
Children Between 6 and 14 years
    &       &       &                   &         
    &       &       & -0.036\sym{***}   &  (0.002)          \\
Log of Age      
    &       &       &                   &         
    &       &       & -0.399\sym{***}   &  (0.013)          \\
Sex of Respondent
    &       &       &                   &         
    &       &       & -0.182\sym{***}   &  (0.005)          \\
Years of Schooling
    &       &       &                   &         
    &       &       & -0.041\sym{***}   &  (0.000)          \\
Marital Status  
    &       &       &                   &         
    &       &       & -0.005            &  (0.006)          \\
Spouse Employment
    &       &       &                   &         
    &       &       &  0.05\sym{***}    &  (0.005)          \\
Physical Activity
    &       &       &                   &         
    &       &       &  0.5\sym{***}     &  (0.005)          \\
Ever Consumed alcohol
    &       &       &                   &         
    &       &       & -0.004            &  (0.005)          \\
Ever Smoked     
    &       &       &                   &         
    &       &       & -0.008            &  (0.004)          \\
\hline
Observations    
    &{5035} &       & {5035}            &         
    &{2744} &       & {4921}            &                   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[] Standardized beta coefficients; Standard errors in parentheses  
\item[] The dependent variable is equal to 1 if a person is working or looking for work. Health as an indecent variable is defined as 0 if an individual reported poor or fair health status, otherwise, it is 1.
\item[] Source: Authors Calculation from ??
        \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

**Addedndum:**
For the case, that you willing to put standard errors in separate rows, than your table can fit to portrait oriented page:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,  siunitx}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {4}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

    
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty =,
    input-close-uncertainty=,
    table-align-text-pre=false,
    table-align-text-after=false
        }
    \centering
\SetTblrStyle{foot}{font=\footnotesize}
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Effect of Health on Labour force activity in India},
  label = {tab:longtblr?},
  remark{Note} = {Standardized beta coefficients; Standard errors 
                  in parentheses:\newline
                  $^*p<0.1;~^{**}p<0.05;~^{***}p<0.01$.\newline
                  The dependent variable is equal to 1 if a person 
                  is working or looking for work. Health as an indecent variable is defined as 0 if an individual reported poor or fair health status, otherwise, it is 1.}, 
remark{Source} = {Authors Calculation from ??},
                    ]{
       colspec = {@{} X[l] *{4}{Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3{$^{***}$}}]} @{}},
      rowsep=-1pt,
      row{1,2,Z} = {abovesep=2pt},
  row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=3pt},
        row{Z} = {rowsep=2pt},
                     }
    \toprule
    & {{{(1)\\ Null Model}}}    
        & {{{(2)\\ State FE}}}  
            & {{{(3)\\ Household FE}}}   
                & {{{(4)\\ Overall}}}       \\
    \midrule
Health
    & 0.164\TblrNote{***}   
                & 0.168\TblrNote{***} 
                            & 0.199\TblrNote{***} 
                                        & 0.054\TblrNote{***}   \\
    & (0.005)   & (0.005)   & (0.009)   & (0.004)               \\
State
    &           & 0.000     & 0.000     & 0.014\TblrNote{*}     \\      
    &           & (.)       & (.)       & (0.000)               \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Place of residence
    &           &           & 0.000     & -0.031\TblrNote{***}  \\
    &           &           & (.)       &  (0.006)              \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Caste of head of the HH
    &           &           & 0.000     & -0.032\TblrNote{***}  \\  
    &           &           & (.)       &  (0.002)              \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Religion of head of the HH
    &           &           & 0.000     & 0.011\TblrNote{*}     \\ 
    &           &           & (.)       &  (0.003)              \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    MPCE quintile
    &           &           & 0.000     & -0.017\TblrNote{***}  \\   
    &           &           & (.)       &  (0.002)              \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Children Below 5 years
    &           &           &           & -0.017\TblrNote{***}  \\
    &           &           &           &  (0.003)              \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Children Between 6 and 14 years
    &           &           &           & -0.036\TblrNote{***}  \\   
    &           &           &           &  (0.002)              \\
Log of Age
    &           &           &           & -0.399\TblrNote{***}  \\   
    &           &           &           &  (0.013)              \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Sex of Respondent
    &           &           &           & -0.182\TblrNote{***}  \\   
    &           &           &           &  (0.005)              \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Years of Schooling
    &           &           &           & -0.041\TblrNote{***}  \\
    &           &           &           &  (0.000)              \\
Marital Status
    &           &           &           & -0.005                \\
    &           &           &           &  (0.006)              \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Spouse Employment
    &           &           &           &  0.05\TblrNote{***}   \\    
    &           &           &           &  (0.005)              \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Physical Activity
    &           &           &           &  0.5\TblrNote{***}    \\
    &           &           &           & (0.005)               \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Ever Consumed alcohol
    &           &           &           & -0.004                \\
    &           &           &           &  (0.005)              \\
Ever Smoked
    &           &           &           & -0.008                \\      
    &           &           &           &  (0.004)              \\
    \midrule
Observations
    & {5035}    &{5035}     & {2744}    & {4921}                \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it was quite helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use a STATA generated table as is, forget it. They ***must*** be edited.

The main problem with your code is that the long table note is not split across lines, but there's a much easier solution: typeset the table notes *outside* the table.

Here's my proposal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\NewDocumentCommand{\sym}{m}{\ensuremath{^{#1}}}

\caption{Effect of Health on Labour force activity in India}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{4}{
    S[table-format=-1.3\sym{***}]
    @{\ }
    S[input-open-uncertainty=,input-close-uncertainty=,table-format=(1.3)]
  }
  @{}
}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(3)}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(4)} \\
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Null Model}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{State FE}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Household FE}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Overall} \\
\midrule
Health & 0.164\sym{***}& (0.005) & 0.168\sym{***} & (0.005)& 0.199\sym{***}& (0.009)& 0.054\sym{***}&  (0.004)\\
State           &                  &         &    0.000         &      (.)&    0.000         &      (.)&    0.014\sym{*}  &  (0.000)\\
Place of residence&                  &         &                  &         &    0.000         &      (.)&   -0.031\sym{***}&  (0.006)\\
Caste of head of the HH&                  &         &                  &         &    0.000         &      (.)&   -0.032\sym{***}&  (0.002)\\
Religion of head of the HH&                  &         &                  &         &    0.000         &      (.)&    0.011\sym{*}  &  (0.003)\\
MPCE quintile   &                  &         &                  &         &    0.000         &      (.)&   -0.017\sym{***}&  (0.002)\\
Children Below 5 years&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.017\sym{***}&  (0.003)\\
Children Between 6 and 14 years&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.036\sym{***}&  (0.002)\\
Log of Age      &                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.399\sym{***}&  (0.013)\\
Sex of Respondent&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.182\sym{***}&  (0.005)\\
Years of Schooling&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.041\sym{***}&  (0.000)\\
Marital Status  &                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.005         &  (0.006)\\
Spouse Employment&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &    0.05\sym{***}&  (0.005)\\
Physical Activity&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &    0.5\sym{***}&  (0.005)\\
Ever Consumed alcohol&                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.004         &  (0.005)\\
Ever Smoked     &                  &         &                  &         &                  &         &   -0.008         &  (0.004)\\
\midrule
Observations & {5035} && {5035} && {2744} && {4921} & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip
\footnotesize

Standardized beta coefficients; Standard errors in parentheses

Source: Authors Calculation from

The dependent variable is equal to 1 if a person is working or looking for work. 
Health as an independent variable is defined as 0 if an individual reported poor 
or fair health status,otherwise, it is 1.

\sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]